# How to reduce the number of row repetitions in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates, distinct, data-analysis

I want to clean my data reducing the number of duplicates. I do not want to delete ALL duplicates.

How can I get a numpy array with certain number of duplicates?

Suppose, I have

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[5,5,5],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

and I set number of duplicates as 2.

And the output should be like

```
x
>>[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[5,5,5]]
```

or

```
x
>>[[5,5,5],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

It does not meter in my task

Comment: Another advice: Make the input data executable, so that we may just copy it to our console. And also add something that shows what you have done so far.

Comment: Yes, but that does not help us. Just post some code so we can execute it.

Comment: @Scotty1- did it

Comment: Thanks! Now there is one last thing: You have added `x` as a list, whereas you stated that you have a numpy array. Do you have a list or a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though using list appending as an intermediate step is not always a good idea when you already have numpy arrays, in this case it is by far the cleanest way to do it:

```
def n_uniques(arr, max_uniques):
    uniq, cnts = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    arr_list = []
    for i in range(cnts.size):
        num = cnts[i] if cnts[i] <= max_uniques else max_uniques
        arr_list.extend([uniq[i]] * num)
    return np.array(arr_list)

x = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],
              [5,5,5],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3],])

reduced_arr = n_uniques(x, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was kind of tricky, but you can actually do that without loops and preserving the relative order in the original array with something like this (in this case the first repetitions are preserved):

```
import numpy as np

def drop_extra_repetitions(x, max_reps):
    # Find unique rows
    uniq, idx_inv, counts = np.unique(x, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    # Compute number of repetitions of each different row
    counts_clip = np.minimum(counts, max_reps)
    # Array alternating between valid unique row indices and -1 ([0, -1, 1, -1, ...])
    idx_to_repeat = np.stack(
        [np.arange(len(uniq)), -np.ones(len(uniq), dtype=int)], axis=1).ravel()
    # Number of repetitions for each of the previous indices
    idx_repeats_clip = np.stack([counts_clip, counts - counts_clip], axis=1).ravel()
    # Valid unique row indices are repetead at most max_reps,
    # extra repetitions are filled with -1
    idx_clip_sorted = np.repeat(idx_to_repeat, idx_repeats_clip)
    # Sorter for inverse index - that is, sort the indices in the input array
    # according to their corresponding unique row index
    sorter = np.argsort(idx_inv)
    # The final inverse index is the same as the original but with -1 on extra repetitions
    idx_inv_final = np.empty(len(sorter), dtype=int)
    idx_inv_final[sorter] = idx_clip_sorted
    # Return the array reconstructed from the inverse index without the positions with -1
    return uniq[idx_inv_final[idx_inv_final >= 0]]

x = [[5, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
max_reps = 2

print(drop_extra_repetitions(x, max_reps))
# [[5 5 5]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [5 5 5]]
```

If you do not need to preserve the order at all, then you can simply do:

```
import numpy as np

def drop_extra_repetitions(x, max_reps):
    uniq, counts = np.unique(x, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    # Repeat each unique row index at most max_reps
    ret_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(uniq)), np.minimum(counts, max_reps))
    return uniq[ret_idx]

x = [[5, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [5, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
max_reps = 2

print(drop_extra_repetitions(x, max_reps))
# [[1 2 3]
#  [1 2 3]
#  [5 5 5]
#  [5 5 5]]
```